# uipath studio how to show consolidated results?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

i am testing Rest API requests using http request nearly 14 requests are being checked instead of showing for each http request is there anyway we can show consolidated output which one is success which is failed at last? seeking your expertise.

Comment: You could use the Test Activities and Test cases. With that you can also define multiple different input values for the same request. https://docs.uipath.com/studio/standalone/2023.10/user-guide/test-explorer